awk/sed in loop to replace numbers (with result of computation)
I am relatively new to awk and sed. 
I have a file with more than 30000 rows/lines; e.g.,
Direct configuration= 5 
0.86331344 0.14835363 0.01770155
0.83813858 0.74789354 0.31772038
0.89805721 0.04407727 0.09535924
0.01960635 0.13639495 0.08503445
0.60042328 0.54392927 0.30715808
0.89205404 0.17572676 0.17279700
            ︙
        (up to 135 lines of three-column numerical data)
            ︙
Direct configuration= 10 
0.86331344 0.14835363 0.01770155 
0.83813858 0.74789354 0.31772038 
0.89805721 0.04407727 0.09535924 ........... 

I want to add a specific number, say 1000,
to each of the numerical term after Direct Configuration=. 
More specifically, I need to replace each numerical term
after Direct Configuration= with the sum of the term + 1000,
but keep the rest of the file the same. 
Is there any bash/awk/sed/python script to do that in a loop?
P.S. The line Direct configuration= occurs after each 135 lines,
i.e., in line 1, 137, 272 and so on.

sed would be less useful as its language doesn't have any support for artithmetics.

please update the question with the expected results for the 2 sets of sample inputs; also update the question with your coding attempt(s) and the (wrong) results generated by your code

If you need to increment the digit after the matching string:
With awk, capable of nice arithmetic by design:
awk -v val=1000 '/Direct configuration/{$NF+=val}1' file
Direct configuration= 1005
0.86331344 0.14835363 0.01770155
0.83813858 0.74789354 0.31772038
0.89805721 0.04407727 0.09535924
0.01960635 0.13639495 0.08503445
0.60042328 0.54392927 0.30715808
0.89205404 0.17572676 0.17279700


what-does-a-number-do-after-curly-braces

Using perl:
$ perl -s -pe 's.Direct configuration= \K\d+.$&+$var.e' -- -var=1000 your-file


variables can be -set¹ from command line.
substitues text while \Keeping matched text before \K.
/eval² is a substitution modifier.


¹ See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34868254
²Only the substitution operator allows the use of /e modifier. When used, the replacement operand is evaluated as if with eval{..}, the result of which is substituted for the matched text. From Mastering Regular Expressions by Jeffrey Friedl.

Using any awk:
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="= "} NF>1{$2+=1000} 1' file
Direct configuration= 1005
0.86331344 0.14835363 0.01770155
0.83813858 0.74789354 0.31772038
0.89805721 0.04407727 0.09535924
0.01960635 0.13639495 0.08503445
0.60042328 0.54392927 0.30715808
0.89205404 0.17572676 0.17279700

